# How to find the pod name given a container ID

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Is there a way to find the pod name for a given Docker container ID?

I can do it the other way round "kubectl describe pods" but then I have to run it on all the pods.

Comment: What's your objective here? Maybe there's a different way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can get the pod name given a container ID using the following `kubectl` request:

```
kubectl get pod -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.status.containerStatuses[].containerID=="docker://<container_id>")]}{.metadata.name}{end}' -n <namespace>
```

where `<container_id>` is the long docker container ID and `<namespace>` is namespace which we can skip if our pod is in default namespace.

For example:

```
kubectl get pod -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.status.containerStatuses[].containerID=="docker://686bc30be6e870023dcf611f7a7808516e041c892a236e565ba2bd3e0569ff7a")]}{.metadata.name}{end}'
nginx-deployment-569477d6d8-xtf42
```

Comment: For some reason, it is not working in my environment.

Comment: @Hem Maybe your pod is not in `default` namespace? You need to add `-n <namespace>` in the end of the `kubectl` command then.

Comment: You can add `--all-namespaces` if you don't know the namespace.

Comment: This doesn't work for me:
```error: there is no need to specify a resource type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form (e.g. 'kubectl get resource/<resource_name>' instead of 'kubectl get resource resource/<resource_name>'
```

Comment: @simon Which command did you try to execute?